# Math operation in the test expression of the `for` loop - perfomance, optimisation

Tags: c, performance

I am interested, which of these forms of the `for` loop test expression is more right (from the point of the performance and the good code practice):

```
for(i = 0; i < size - 1; i++) {
    do something
}
```

or

```
int decreased_size = size - 1;
for(i = 0; i < decreased_size; i++) {
    do something
}
```

Is the test expression `size - 1` calculated every time in the first example or does the compiler optimize it to the constant value, so there is no need to creating an additional variable `decreased_size`?

I was creating an additional variable all the time, but now, looking at the others solutions on the [Codeforces](http://codeforces.com/?locale=en), I doubts - whether it makes sense?

**Compiler**: GCC version 5.4.0 20160609

Comment: Depends if the compiler can determine with 100% certainty that `size` can't change within the loop. But usually that extra var is a waste of typing.

Comment: Build an optimized executable. Check the generated machine code. That's the only way to see what the compiler will be doing.

Comment: 3rd choice: `for(i = 0; i + 1 < size; i++) {` will not overflow while both of OP's `for` loops may with `size == INT_MIN`.  What is best to use here depends on context not shown.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No one makes more sense than other. Indeed, with optimization, it produces same code : https://godbolt.org/g/vzVJVF

Secondly, time consumed by `size-1` is, in most case, negligible vis-a-vis of time consumed by action in loop, so optimize this part has a really small effect on system.

In conclusion, optimize only when it's needed (so you see that there is an time/memory issue). In every day, prefer a readable, easy to understand code.

Comment: You didn't change `size - 1` part to the `decreased_size` in the second `for(int i = 0; i < size - 1; i++) {`. Thus, you have two same loops. I did it and the difference in the assemble code has appeared.

Comment: Corrected version: https://godbolt.org/g/vzVJVF

Comment: @MiniMax thanks a lot

Comment: You right, with the `-O3` option - no difference. Without this option difference exists.

Comment: Yes of course, without optimization, compiler do exactly what you wrote. But this case falls under my second points ;)

Comment: @MiniMax without this option, discussing performance is meaningless, so any difference is irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @Garf365. If you also look at https://www.tutorialspoint.com/assembly_programming/assembly_loops.htm you will see that loop count is loaded into register before loop starts and so `size-1` has to be computed and loaded **only once**.